# Lazarus - проблема с кодировкой

Tags: delphi, кодировка, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

Здравствуйте!

Есть код:

```
function LocalAppDataPath: string;
const
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT=0;
var
  path: array[0..255] of char;
  f: TextFile;
begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,0,SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,@path[0]);
  Result:=path;
  showmessage(path);
  AssignFile(f,'D:\loglol.txt');
  Rewrite(f);
  WriteLn(f,path);
  closefile(f);
end;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при выводе пути к папке через `showmessage`, показываются знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы. Решив для начала посмотреть, что это за кодировка, я добавил код, который создает файл и записывает туда этот путь. Меня поразило, но когда я увидел этот файл, то кириллица отображалась как надо, при том, что двумя строками выше я вывожу эту же самую строку через `showmessage`, и кодировка слетает.

Путь до папки в файле:

> C:\Users\ваня123\AppData\Local

Путь до папки в showmessage:

> C:\Users\????123\AppData\Local

Каким образом можно вывести данную строку с показом кириллицы? Она мне нужна для создания файлов.

Comment: Посмотрите тип последнего параметра в объявлении `SHGetFolderPath` - он принимает PWideChar или PAnsiChar? Или же - куда "смотрит" эта функция - на SHGetFolderPathA или SHGetFolderPathW ? По всей видимости, у вас нестыковка AnsiString - WideString.

Comment: @kami, `(HWND:hwnd;csidl:longint;htoken:THandle;dwflags:dword;pszpath:lpstr):HResult;StdCall; external 'shell32' name 'SHGetFolderPathA'`.

Comment: попробуйте объявить path как `array ... of AnsiChar`. Возможно, потребуются дополнительные явные преобразования, например `Result:=AnsiString(path)`

Comment: @kami, изменений нет. Попробовал `Result:=AnsiString(path)` и `Result:=path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Lazarus детская болезнь с кодировками.
Все функции работы с интерфейсом, в том числе и `ShowMessage` работают в кодировку utf8, что вполне логично для системы, изначально ориентированной на Unix-подобные ОС.

Но WinAPI (Например, `SHGetFolderPath`) всегда возвращают в ANSI, в данном случае, вероятнее всего, cp1251.

К сожалению, компилятор не может различать эти две кодировки, и, более того, латиница в них кодируется одинаково, поэтому разработчики у себя не могут это воспроизвести, т.к. они все из англоговорящий стран.

Решение - четко осознавать где у вас ansi, а где utf-8,и по необходимости использовать `AnsiToUtf8` и `Utf8ToAnsi`.

Comment: Так если WinAPI результат возвращает в кодировке ANSI, тогда должна работать функция `AnsiToUtf8`. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: А где она у вас не работает? `Result:=AnsiString(path)` <> `Result:=AnsiToUtf8(path)`

Comment: `AnsiToUtf8` работает, именно благодаря ей работает ваш второй пример с `GetEnvironmentVariable`

Comment: @Alekcvp, не работает в примере, который в вопросе.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, зато он не работает в первом примере.

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, а вы, когда делали присваивание `Result := AnsiToUtf8(path)`, во второй строке так и оставляли `showmessage(*path*);` ?

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, в первом примере его и нет. Попробуйте `ShowMessage(AnsiToUtf8(Path))`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, в комментариях к вопросу я писал, что уже пробовал данные функции. Ничего не менялось.

Comment: @Alekcvp, да... До меня только дошло, надо было через `showmessage` выводить не `path`, а `result`... Поэтому в showmessage я и не видел кириллицы, потому что перекодировку делал в `result`, а `path` был все так же в ANSI. Большое спасибо за помощь =)

Answer (score 1):

Решил данную задачу с использованием функции `GetEnvironmentVariable`.

Код:

```
begin
  Result:=SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable('APPDATA');
  if Result<>'' then
  Result:=ansitoutf8(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Result));
end;
```

И все же помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему код в вопросе не работает с кириллицей.

Answer (score -1):

В исходном коде нужно добавить `AnsiToUtf8` в эту строку:

```
showmessage(AnsiToUtf8(path));
```